# VBA that split data into multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have one master sheet with three columns "ID", "Text" and "Amount"

Sample Data

```
ID | TEXT | AMOUNT

1    JP Morgan     100         
2    Sales 1       200
3    Sales 2       300
4    Chase         400 
5    JP Morgan     500
```

I want based on my text let say if I say Sales and JP in Macro then it filter outs all record of rows in new separate shteet of "Sales" and JP and copy all records there respectively.

I have searched on Google and find out this VBA Macro but it creates new entry bases on unique entries but not based on Like%. I want some help in modification in that

```
Sub parse_data()
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vcol, i As Integer
    Dim icol As Long
    Dim myarr As Variant
    Dim title As String
    Dim titlerow As Integer
    vcol = 2
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
    title = "A1:C1"
    titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
    icol = ws.Columns.Count
    ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"

    For i = 2 To lr
        On Error Resume Next
        If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
            ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
        End If
    Next

    myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
    ws.Columns(icol).Clear

    For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
        ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
        If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
            Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
        Else
            Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        End If
        ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
        Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
    Next

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Not a big issue, but your line `Dim vcol, i As Integer`, `vcol` is declared as type Variant even though you declared `i` as integer. I noticed that you declared everything else specifically so I just thought I'd point that out. You may have even intended for this, but doesn't appear likely due to the rest of your declarations.

Comment: @KDavis, I took this link as a reference and they declared vcol = 1 as in thier example they want unique records from colums 1 and in my case its 2.

Comment: Seems like a Pivot Table may solve this for you, does it have to be a macro and new sheet?

Comment: I would suggest looking into using SQL to retrieve the data from the worksheet, if you are comfortable with it. It will save you from doing all of the acrobatics with dynamic ranges and will make it a lot easier to pass conditions. I find using `ADODB.RecordSet` to be a faster and more flexible alternative than working with worksheets and cell contents. You would need `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library` for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses AutoFilters, and checks if it's running on Mac or Windows

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ParseData()
    Const KEY_WORDS = "DKFLX, FNR"  '<-- Update keywords (adds 2 new sheets at the end)
    Const FILTER_COL = 2            '<-- Update column to filter

    Dim ws As Worksheet, keys As Variant, i As Long, nWs As Worksheet, k As String

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")   '<-- Update sheet name
    keys = Split(KEY_WORDS, ",")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    #If Not Mac Then
        If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.UsedRange.AutoFilter         'Clears existing filters
    #End If

    For i = 0 To UBound(keys)           'Loop all keywords and apply filter
        k = Trim(keys(i)): If Len(k) > 29 Then k = Left(k, 29)    'Check ws name
        If Not WsExists(k) Then
            With ws.UsedRange
                .AutoFilter Field:=FILTER_COL, Criteria1:="=*" & k & "*"
                If .Columns(FILTER_COL).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).CountLarge > 1 Then
                    Set nWs = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
                    .Copy nWs.Cells(1)  'Move visible rows to the new worksheet
                    nWs.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
                    nWs.Name = k
                End If
                #If Not Mac Then
                    .AutoFilter         'Removes previous filter (Windows only)
                #End If
            End With
        End If
    Next
    ws.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Function WsExists(ByVal wsName As String) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name = wsName Then
            WsExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: I tried your snippet and I am getting run time error '1004'
Application defined or Object defined error.

Comment: Yes sheetname is Sheet1

Comment: There is no line number since its not compile time error I believe.
I have uploaded excel sheet for you here https://ufile.io/k3f1o
And I am using Keywords DKFLX and FNR

Comment: I updated the code with the new keyords, I tested it with your file and it works as expected. Try it again with the new keywords (`"DKFLX, FNR"` separated by a comma). Your file is ".xls" - what version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I am using Excel 2016 and precise version is 15.38 (170902)

Comment: And its Excel For Mac that works same as Windows. As I tried other VBA Scripts that works well!

Comment: I don't have a Mac, and without knowing what line is causing the problem I'm not sure what needs to change

Comment: I have one more finding that I copied the text to new sheet and there were no filters then I executed VBA. It gives error but in bottom I can see it works well for one Keyword and filter the records. It was unable to set sheet name as keyword and also due to same error it doesnot run for second keyword

Comment: Ok, I think the error was caused by `Trim()`, I removed that function call, and I removed the space after the comma in the KEY_WORDS. Please try the updated answer again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154790/discussion-between-arslan-pervaiz-and-paul-bica).

Comment: Thanks Paul for all your help :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped; I updated the code to check for Mac version, and it also verifies sheet name length, and if the sheet already exists

Answer (score 0):

I think filters are the answer for this kind of thing.

The range for the code example below looks like this

```
Column A : Header in A1 = Country, A2:A? = Country names
Column B : Header in B1 = Name, B2:B? = Names
Column C : Header in C1 = Gender, C2:C? = F or M
Column D : Header in D1 = Birthday, D2:D? = Dates
```

Code . . .

```
Sub Copy_To_Worksheets()
'Note: This macro use the function LastRow
    Dim My_Range As Range
    Dim FieldNum As Long
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim CCount As Long
    Dim WSNew As Worksheet
    Dim ErrNum As Long

    'Set filter range on ActiveSheet: A1 is the top left cell of your filter range
    'and the header of the first column, D is the last column in the filter range.
    'You can also add the sheet name to the code like this :
    'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D" & LastRow(Worksheets("Sheet1")))
    'No need that the sheet is active then when you run the macro when you use this.
    Set My_Range = Range("A1:D" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))
    My_Range.Parent.Select

    If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Or _
       My_Range.Parent.ProtectContents = True Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, not working when the workbook or worksheet is protected", _
               vbOKOnly, "Copy to new worksheet"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'This example filters on the first column in the range(change the field if needed)
    'In this case the range starts in A so Field:=1 is column A, 2 = column B, ......
    FieldNum = 1

    'Turn off AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    'Add a worksheet to copy the a unique list and add the CriteriaRange
    Set ws2 = Worksheets.Add

    With ws2
        'first we copy the Unique data from the filter field to ws2
        My_Range.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
                Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                CopyToRange:=.Range("A1"), Unique:=True

        'loop through the unique list in ws2 and filter/copy to a new sheet
        Lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each cell In .Range("A2:A" & Lrow)

            'Filter the range
            My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, Criteria1:="=" & _
             Replace(Replace(Replace(cell.Value, "~", "~~"), "*", "~*"), "?", "~?")

            'Check if there are no more then 8192 areas(limit of areas)
            CCount = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            CCount = My_Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) _
                     .Areas(1).Cells.Count
            On Error GoTo 0
            If CCount = 0 Then
                MsgBox "There are more than 8192 areas for the value : " & cell.Value _
                     & vbNewLine & "It is not possible to copy the visible data." _
                     & vbNewLine & "Tip: Sort your data before you use this macro.", _
                       vbOKOnly, "Split in worksheets"
            Else
                'Add a new worksheet
                Set WSNew = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
                On Error Resume Next
                WSNew.Name = cell.Value
                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    ErrNum = ErrNum + 1
                    WSNew.Name = "Error_" & Format(ErrNum, "0000")
                    Err.Clear
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                'Copy the visible data to the new worksheet
                My_Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                With WSNew.Range("A1")
                    ' Paste:=8 will copy the columnwidth in Excel 2000 and higher
                    ' Remove this line if you use Excel 97
                    .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    .Select
                End With
            End If

            'Show all data in the range
            My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum

        Next cell

        'Delete the ws2 sheet
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        On Error GoTo 0

    End With

    'Turn off AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    If ErrNum > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Rename every WorkSheet name that start with ""Error_"" manually" _
             & vbNewLine & "There are characters in the name that are not allowed" _
             & vbNewLine & "in a sheet name or the worksheet already exist."
    End If

    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    My_Range.Parent.Select
    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With

End Sub


Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win006_4.htm

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd solution seems to have worked better for me. I'm looking to add to it the ability to copy a 2nd existing template worksheet rather than adding a new blank worksheet. Additionally, curious if there is a way to generate the new tabs and write to the preferred cells without also writing the header row.

As for the first item, I've tried to replace

```
Set WSNew = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
```

with

```
Set TrdSht = Sheets("Template").Copy(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
```

to match my existing sheet named "Template"

What I end up with is sheet "ws2" does not get deleted, a single copy of "Template" is generated named "Template (2)" and I get a Run-Time Error 13 'Type Mismatch'